# How can I find the configuration file for rsyslog if it's not the default?

Tags: linux, configuration, rsyslog

By default, rsyslog's config file is in /etc/rsyslog.conf. You can set the config file path on startup with the -f /path/to/file option.

My question is: how can you find the config file if it's been set somewhere other than the default?

Comment: `ps -fe | grep rsyslog`? Look to see what's specified on the command line.

Comment: That's a great simple solution that I hadn't considered. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on the software and how it has been configured; `rsyslogd` at least the version present on Centos 7 does close the configuration file after reading it so a tool like `lsof` will not reveal that file once the daemon is up and running:

```
% sudo lsof -p `pidof rsyslogd` | perl -nle 'print for grep -f, split'
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
/usr/sbin/rsyslogd
...
```

The filename does however appear in the process table, which can then be searched for under `/etc` as that's usually where such configuration is hidden:

```
% < /proc/`pidof rsyslogd`/cmdline tr '\0' ' ' ; echo
/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -f /nunca/adivinarás/esto
% sudo grep -r '/nunca/adivinar' /etc
/etc/sysconfig/rsyslog:SYSLOGD_OPTIONS="-f /nunca/adivinarás/esto"
```

On a completely unknown system you may need to use something like SystemTap or `sysdig`—a kernel tracing facility, in other words—and report on what files the daemon uses:

```
% sudo sysdig -p '%fd.name' 'proc.name = rsyslogd' | tee files-used
...
```

And then restart the daemon.

Lacking a kernel tracing facility one may be able to trace the daemon in question with a userland tool such as `strace` or `ktrace` and from the system calls possibly figure out what the configuration file is. You may need to compare the trace output from a sensibly configured system to figure out where to look for the configuration file read.

Comment: This is thorough, and I appreciate the different approaches. I won't always have access to ps results so this was very helpful.